# Need Help in Selection of Ajax Framework

Tags: ajax, spring, hibernate

My project's domain is of eTendering. And we are planing to use Spring and Hibernate in the architecture and in presentation Spring MVC but we want look and feel like silverlight of .Net or Flex of adobe in short we are planning for Ajax framework in presentaion. So SpringMVC will be worthfull? I have seen wicket and openxava but I am still confused so please suggest correct option in terms of my domain's complexity.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on your needs:

- Spring MVC - this option will leave you with writing AJAX on your own (via JQuery for instance) along with HTML and so forth. It might be tedious, but you're controlling everything. It's also up to you what will be the quality of your resulting HTML and how good it will be indexed by SEO.
- JSF - this option provides you with a number of components and allows you to create AJAX based forms and handles it out-of-box. But when it comes to writing custom components, it won't that easy as just writing JS/JQuery on your own. Also it generates not that pretty HTML which is not of that good quality and you might be less indexed by SEOs.
- GWT - this choice would mean that you don't write JS, instead you write logic in Java and then it transforms to JS. From one hand it will provide you with good-looking AJAX-based app where you don't need to write JS, from the other hand it's a) pretty complicated to write really good-looking apps UI b) it will add another step in your development cycle (it takes pretty much time when you generate that JS) c) it almost won't allow your pages to be indexed. Also, if it comes to such derivatives as SmartGWT, they provide a large set of cool-looking components, but they always require money for support.
- Vaadin - this is AJAX based framework that partially generates Java to JS, but it also sends requests go server for logic execution (of course in GWT this happens as well, but not that often, GWT tries to execute logic on client). It takes less time to compile sources to JS and it's also almost impossible to make pages being indexed.
- ZK - another AJAX based framework. unlike other frameworks that allow you to work with only one pattern, it can work in MVC, MVP, MVVM modes. It doesn't compile Java sources to JS thus all the requests go to the server (I've heard about internal company's benchmarks that showed it was actually faster than GWT, but I think it depends on your processing logic). SEO won't make it with ZK at all, but it's possible to include ZK components into JSP pages (though this functionality is not free) which makes it possible to kill both birds. It will be not trivial to write your own components with ZK, but it has a wide range of ready-to-use components.

So you should consider several things: SEO, money you can give for the framework, how much AJAX you need and do you want to write it on your own, etc.
Also pay attention to those patterns I mentioned: MVP for instance is suitable for complicated interfaces and is supported by GWT, Vaadin, ZK. MVVM is very cool because of its binding and is supported by JSF and ZK.